# Find out if image exists at url with wildcard

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to display an image, but revert to a default image if it doesn't exist. But the image can have any image extension. So how can I add a wildcard to the `$.get()` function below to make it look for any file with the right filename?

```
$.get('path/to/file.*')
    .done(function() {

    }).fail(function() {

    });
```

Comment: you can't. You will need to specify the exact path when trying to load a resource. You could create a list of valid extensions and try them in sequence.

Comment: The `$.get()` function doesn't look for an image, it requests a specific resource at the specified URL. There could be multiple images that exist on the web server with URLs that differ only in the extension - which image would you want to select in that case?

Comment: How do you get image url? You want images like http://example.com/*.jpg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `img` element raises an `error` event when the src fails. As such you can use the following jQuery without the need for AJAX requests (which would mean nImages+1 requests being made):

```
$('img').on('error', function() {
    $(this).prop('src', '/path-to/default-image.png');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution that will try a list of extensions and if none works will apply the default image is

```
var validImageExtensions = ['jpg','png','gif'];

function imageOrDefault( path, defaultPath, target, index ){
    var img = $('<img>'),
        extensionIndex = index || 0;

    $(img)
        .on('load', function(){
            target.prop('src', img.prop('src'));
        })
        .on('error', function(){
            if (extensionIndex === validImageExtensions.length){
                target.prop('src', defaultPath);
            } else {
                imageOrDefault( path, defaultPath, target, extensionIndex +1);
            }
        });
    img.prop('src', path + '.' + validImageExtensions[extensionIndex]);
}
```

Usage

```
imageOrDefault('path/to/image/without-extension', 'path/to/default.png', $('.target-selector'));
```